# Iteration and comparison in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I have a list of values (the order of the list matters):

```
lst = [7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7]
```

My goal is to find the most important loss. For example, in the list above the most important loss is `4`, because `7 - 3 = 4`.

How can I iterate a list, so that if `lst[x] > lst[x + 1]` I go on to the next one?

In other words, I am looking for the largest difference between a larger element and a smaller element that comes later in the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You define loss as the difference between an element `l[i] - l[i+x]` where `l[i:i+x+1]` is a decreasing subsequence.

Then we can traverse the list an have a loss counter on each decreasing sub sequence, keeping the max loss.

```
from itertools import chain
from math import inf

def max_loss(l):
    a, b, max_loss = iter(l), chain(l, (inf,)), 0
    top = next(b, None)

    for prev, curr in zip(a, b):
        if curr > prev:
            max_loss, top = max(top - prev, max_loss), curr

    return max_loss
```

Example:

```
l = [7, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 4, 7]
loss = max_loss(l)
loss # 4
```

Comment: This dont work on every dataset, Im trying to debug it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @remc what does not work? Provide details and examples of input-output. I read your other solution required a lot of memory, this one should be both O(n) in time and O(1) in memory.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon in fact, it work completly ! Thanls for your help :D

Answer (score -1):

To get the largest decrease between consecutive elements, it's not pretty, but we could make a `for` loop like so:

```
data = [7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7]

largestDrop = 0
currentDrop = 0
previousValue = None

for currentValue in data:
    if previousValue != None and previousValue >= currentValue:
        currentDrop += previousValue - currentValue
    else:
        currentDrop = 0

    if currentDrop > largestDrop:
        largestDrop = currentDrop

    previousValue = currentValue
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a brute-force method:

```
A = [7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7]

res = max(A[j] - A[i] for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(i, len(A)))

print(res)  # 4
```

The idea is to take every number and every subsequent number pairwise, calculate difference, and then take the maximum of these differences. Using a generator expression as above means that no intermediary lists are built in the process.

Answer (score -2):

This is possible using vectorised logic via 3rd party library `numpy`.

The idea is to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to take the difference between the array and its transposed representation. Then take the maximum of the lower triangle from the resulting array.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7])

B = A - A[:, None]
res = np.max(B[np.tril_indices(B.shape[0])])

print(res)
4
```